# How come printing &some_buf[0] and &some_buf give different outputs?

Tags: c++, g++

```
char buffer[4];
std::cout << &buffer << std::endl;
std::cout << &buffer[0] << std::endl;
```

When I run this code the first line is the hex address of first element in the buffer. The second line is four question marks (unless I cast as a null-pointer).

How is the second statement different from the first (semantically, they are the same?)? 
Why does the second line appear as question marks and not random garbage characters?

Comment: `char*` is handled different from `void*` with `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, T)`.

Comment: "Pointer to array of `T`" and "pointer to `T`"  are not semantically equivalent.   `buffer` would be equivalent to `&buffer[0]` in that context, but not `&buffer`.

Comment: @molbdnilo, yes! That's where my understanding failed. I thought of both statements as "memory address of first element of buffer" rather than "pointer to array of T" and "pointer to T", but I know better now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&buffer` gives you the address of the buffer, in an appropriate pointer type. That type is `char (*)[4]`.

`&buffer[0]` gives you the address of the first buffer element (a `char`), so the address is of type `char*`.

The standard stream classes have an overload that handles a `char const*`, but no overload that handles a `char (*)[4]`. There is however  a general overload for pointers, that accepts a `void*`. So the pointer to array is converted implicitly to a `void*`, and passed to that overload. You therefore see the address of the buffer.

In the second case, if `buffer` was initialized properly, you'd see its contents printed (what the "c-string" overload does). However, since you did not initialize it, your code has undefined behavior. The mere attempt to print the buffer has no well defined consequence.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'd like to ask a follow up question. Would there be any difference between a pointer of type char (*)[4] and, say, a pointer of char (*)[10]? C++ doesn't keep track of the length of arrays anyway, why couldn't we call it a char (*)[n] instead?

Comment: @Locus - C++ most definitly does keep track of the size. The size is part of the type (`char[10]` for instance). What you are confusing it with is array decaying.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't even know what array decaying was and thought that was the 'normal' situation.

Answer (score 4):

`&buffer` is the address of the buffer. `&buffer[0]` is the address of the first character in the buffer. here in your case a garbage value that is because you didn't initialize it. Try to initialize it:

```
char buffer[] = "Hello there!";
std::cout << &buffer << std::endl; 
std::cout << &buffer[0] << std::endl; // print from first element to the end(until the first null-character)
std::cout << &buffer[4] << std::endl; // print from fifth element to the end
```

The output:

```
0018FF38
Hello there!
o there!
```

- I think it is a problem of `osstream insertion operator <<` which assumes you to pass a `char*` and you pass to it the address of a character so as I guess it's a UB.
- To get the address of the character you have to cast it to `void*`:

  ```
  std::cout << static_cast < void* >(&buffer[0]) << std::endl;
  std::cout << static_cast < void* >(&buffer[1]) << std::endl;
  ```

The output:

```
   0018FF38
   0018FF39
```

To confirm that it's an `ostream <<` issue try to use `printf`:

```
printf("&buffer[0]: %p \n", &buffer[0]);
```

The output:

```
&buffer[0]: 0018FF38
```